# Using JTreeTable

Tags: java, jtable, jtree, jtreetable

I need to use a JTreeTable but even after searching for hours, I couldn't find any nice tutorial on JtreeTable or even a simple code from which I can understand.

It would be very helpful if anyone can suggest me a nice tutorial or simple code depicting the use of JtreeTable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find it on: [treetable1](http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~cs3283/ftp/Java/swingConnect/tech_topics/TreeTableExample0.java)

Also you can find example at: [TreeTableExample2.java](http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~cs3283/ftp/Java/swingConnect/tech_topics/tables_trees_2/TreeTableExample2.java)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Above links appear to be dead due to Oracle moving things around

Comment: The links work but they are missing separate components (`FileSystemModel`)

Answer (score 2):

If you are happy to use a 3rd party library [SwingX](http://swinglabs.org/) contains JXTreeTable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can use 3rd party library and infact I have been trying to understand JXTreeTable, but I am not able to find any good tutorial on JXTreeTable.

Comment: Yes. Useful as SwingX is there isn't much in the way of documentation or tutorials for it. SwingX comes with FileSystemModel and SimpleFileSystemModel for the tree table. Maybe you should start by looking at how they are implemented.