# How to create in Java Swing, an interface like Explorer(File) of Windows?

Tags: java, swing

I want to create a Swing interface that allow me to do browse within folders and can doing superior folder return. I've tried to do with Jtree, but I want have a different view of that. I try JFileChooser, but not for me.
I want effect double click onto folders, and enter inside, and return into parent Folder, and see type of extension, size, Date of last modify or date of creation. In short, as a windows explorer.
Someone can help me?
I will post an example:
[E.g. immage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOQFV.png)

Comment: we might be able to help you, when you come up with specific questions.

Comment: You know an alternative to JTree and JFileChooser to do that?
Thanks you

Comment: *"but I want have a different view of that"* - Then customise it.  `JTree` is just a hierarchical view, if you want the "file listing" then you'll probably want to have a look at `JList`. *"I want effect double click onto folders, and enter inside, and return into parent Folder, and see type of extension, size, Date of last modify or date of creation"* - All of it's possible, but you're going to have to put each part together yourself. As it stands the question is simply to broad

Answer (score 1):

You can start using source from [here](http://www.pushing-pixels.org/2007/07/22/showing-the-file-system-as-a-swing-jtree.html) (JTree with filesystem model). Also you can try [JTreeTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826475/using-jtreetable), there are many examples how to use it (even customize it using renderers from first [link](http://www.pushing-pixels.org/2007/07/22/showing-the-file-system-as-a-swing-jtree.html)).

[image]

Comment: Thanks!
JTreeTable, is closer to my needs, but, can I have a view different? Can I open a folder without tree view? 
Anyway, now I read the documentation

Comment: @JoeJoe [How to Use Trees](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html)

Comment: The Documentation of JTreeTable @MadProgrammer :-D

Comment: @JoeJoe I prefer JXTreeTable from SwingLabs SwingX project, but that's me

Comment: Thank @MadProgrammer. I try to use JXTreeTable.